# Beautifulsoup and Panda - help modify code for multipage

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

So I wrote this code to scrape data from a website.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

page = requests.get('https://sofifa.com/shortlist/32931')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
dados = soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile("/player/"))
capa = soup.find('article')
capa1 = capa.find('div' , {'class': 'card card-border mb-2 fixed-width'})
time = capa1.find('div' , {'class': 'card-title h5'}).string

records = []
for nomes in dados:
    nome = nomes.string
    records.append((nome))

import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook

book = load_workbook('Tabela Pipoco 2019.xlsx')
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Tabela Pipoco 2019.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
writer.book = book
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)
df = pd.DataFrame(records, columns=[time])
df.to_excel(writer, "Times", index=False, encoding='utf-8', startcol=0)
writer.save()
```

The thing is that I would like to make this with 10 different pages! Due to my lack of knowledge, I wrote 10 different codes on jupyter notebook and run them all.

the only thing that changes in the codes as these two lines:

```
page = requests.get('https://sofifa.com/shortlist/32931')
```

and

```
df.to_excel(writer, "Times", index=False, encoding='utf-8', startcol=0)
```

So, on the first line, we will change the ending number with specific numbers (32931, 32882, 32589) and so on.

On the second line, what changes is the `startcol=`, that will be (0 for the first page, 3 for the second, 6 for third and so on)

How do I put thins on a single code?

Thank you, guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When you’ve written the same code 3 times, write a function (c) [David Robinson](https://twitter.com/drob/status/928447584712253440https://)

You can wrap your code with a function that takes two parameters: `url` and `startcol`, then call this function in a loop for different inputs. For example:

```
# Define a function
def your_func_to_avoid_writing_the_same_code_ten_times(url, col):
    page = requests.get(url)  
    # ... missed code for better formatting
    df.to_excel(writer, "Times", index=False, encoding='utf-8', startcol=col)
    writer.save()

url_list = ['https://sofifa.com/shortlist/32931', 'https://sofifa.com/shortlist/32882'] # And so on

# Initialize columns counter
col = 0
# Call the function and update the column
for i in range(len(url_list)): 
    print(your_func_to_avoid_writing_the_same_code_ten_times(url_list[i], col))
    col += 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make a list of the pages and then assign a variable for each page bu using indexes. for eg:

```
page_list = ['https://sofifa.com/shortlist/32931', 'https://sofifa.com/shortlist/32941',            'https://sofifa.com/shortlist/32931']
page1 = page_list[0]
page2 = page_list[1]
page3 = page_list[2]
```

you could do the same for the the pdf to excel part